# Integer division optimization MSVC C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, integer, division

I'm trying to reduce the CPU usage of a portion of my code, taking 40% of the CPU power. The portion is this one:

```
void CalibrationFunction(cv::Mat* pMatSrc, cv::Mat* pMatDst, 
                         cv::Mat* pBlack, cv::Mat* pWhite, INT32 nRadioFactor)
{
  if (pMatSrc && pMatDst && pMatSrc->data && pMatDst->data)
  {    
    for (int i = 0; i < pMatSrc->size[0]; i++)
    {
      UINT16* pBlackVal = (UINT16*)(pBlack->data + i*pBlack->step[0]);
      UINT16* pWhiteVal = (UINT16*)(pWhite->data + i*pWhite->step[0]);
      UINT16* pData = (UINT16*)(pMatSrc->data + i*pMatSrc->step[0]);
      INT32 nDif;
      UINT16 un16Value;
      for (int j = 0; j < pMatSrc->size[1]; j++) 
      {
        nDif = (*pData) - (*pBlackVal);
        un16Value = (UINT16)min(65535, (max(0, nDif) * nRadioFactor / max(1, (*pWhiteVal))));
        pBlackVal++;
        pWhiteVal++;
        pData++;

        int i0 = 0, i1 = j, i2 = i;
        *(UINT16*)(pMatDst->data + i0 * pMatDst->step[0] + i1 * pMatDst->step[1] + i2 * pMatDst->step[2]) = un16Value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Multithreading is already implemented: 8 threads are used.

I looked at SIMD with integer arithmetic operation, but as there is an integer division, it seems this is not the way to proceed. I looked at optimized integer division libraries, but they all seem to only be effective when all the integers are divided by the same denominator, which is not the case here.

Does someone have a lead to follow? I'm very open to exotic solution (compile the code in another language and call it from the current solution, etc), the only restriction is this has to stay a MSVC project, using MSVC compiler.

I've seen that Intel implemented integer division with SMID, maybe I should compile this piece of code with the Intel compiler, and call the generated binary from the current solution (I have an Intel compiler), but this solution would only work on my computer and would be, in my opinion, "too custom".

**EDIT**

I finally managed to use SIMD however. The trick was, for the division, to cast the vector of 8 integers of 16 bits into 2 vectors of four float of 32 bits, and then I could divide them, because there are some function to divide floats in SIMD. After the division, recast in order to have 16 bits integer results. 
The new function, using SIMD, is 6 times faster, which is enough at this moment. I keep in mind all your remarks, as they could be helpful if this portion of my solution become again a bottleneck.

**EDIT 2**

As requested, here is the new code:

```
void CalibrationRadioSIMD(UINT16* pBlackVal, UINT16* pWhiteVal, UINT16* pData, UINT16* pResult, int size, int nRadioFactor = 2)
{

    for (int hop = 0; hop < 100; hop++) {
        UINT16* pResultTmp = pResult;
        UINT16* pDataTmp = pData;
        UINT16* pBlackValTmp = pBlackVal;
        UINT16* pWhiteValTmp = pWhiteVal;
        __m128i radio;

        radio.m128i_i32[0] = nRadioFactor;
        radio.m128i_i32[1] = nRadioFactor;
        radio.m128i_i32[2] = nRadioFactor;
        radio.m128i_i32[3] = nRadioFactor;
        for (int j = 0; j < size / 8; j++)
        {
            //
            // nDif = max(0, (*pData) - (*pBlackVal));
            // 
            // 1/ Loads 128-bit value
            //    Address p must be 16-byte aligned. 
            //    For the unaligned version, see _mm_loadu_si128.
            __m128i reg_a = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)pDataTmp);
            __m128i reg_B = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)pBlackValTmp);
            __m128i reg_white = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)pWhiteValTmp);
            pDataTmp += 8;
            pBlackValTmp += 8;
            pWhiteValTmp += 8;

            // 2/ Subtracts the 8 unsigned 16-bit integers of b from the 8 unsigned 16-bit integers of a and saturates.
            __m128i reg_diff = _mm_subs_epu16(reg_a, reg_B);


            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // unpack your vector of 8 x 16 bit unsigned shorts into two vectors of 32 bit unsigned ints, :
            __m128i xlo = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_diff, _mm_set1_epi16(0));
            __m128i xhi = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg_diff, _mm_set1_epi16(0));

            // This instruction multiplies two sets of 32-bit signed integers.
            __m128i mullo = _mm_mullo_epi32(xlo, radio);
            __m128i mulhi = _mm_mullo_epi32(xhi, radio);

            // convert each of these vectors to float
            __m128 ylo = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(mullo);
            __m128 yhi = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(mulhi);


            // Meme question que pour xlo et xhi
            __m128i i32_whitelo = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_white, _mm_set1_epi16(0));
            __m128i i32_whitehi = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg_white, _mm_set1_epi16(0));

            __m128 f32_white_lo = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(i32_whitelo);
            __m128 f32_white_hi = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(i32_whitehi);

            __m128 f32_res_lo = _mm_div_ps(ylo, f32_white_lo);
            __m128 f32_res_hi = _mm_div_ps(yhi, f32_white_hi);

            // Reconvertir en entier 16 bits

            __m128i n32_res_lo = _mm_cvtps_epi32(f32_res_lo);
            __m128i n32_res_hi = _mm_cvtps_epi32(f32_res_hi);

            // Put result into result vector
            UINT16* f32_res_lo_i16 = (UINT16*)&n32_res_lo;
            UINT16* f32_res_hi_i16 = (UINT16*)&n32_res_hi;
            int l = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                *(pResultTmp + k + 0) = *(f32_res_lo_i16 + l);
                *(pResultTmp + k + 4) = *(f32_res_hi_i16 + l);
                l += 2;
            }
            pResultTmp += 8;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So this function takes a lot of processing power, but is it *slow*? Or rather does it *feel* slow? Often "good enough" actually *is* good enough.

Comment: Usually we try to get all CPU-s and sometimes also GPU occupied since we want things to process faster.

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question then. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend that you go down the SIMD route until you've eliminated any memory related performance issues.

What I mean is, glancing through the code, I think the performance of your code might be limited by unnecessary waits on memory rather than computations.

## Benchmark

First off, establish a reproducible way of benchmarking your code. I'm assuming you've already done this considering you're saying it's using 40% of your CPU time. Measure the runtime of this code and nothing else, do it 5 times and record the fastest time. That's the best of 5 value and it should get you pretty far.

The best of N approach to measuring runtimes is good under the assumption that any slowdowns are caused by random other things happening on the computer. This can be other programs doing background work for example. The idea is that the fastest runtime you record is the least affected by random outside noise.

## Help the compiler

The next step is to do simple code transformations such as moving memory reads outside of loops that don't have to be in loops. I know this sounds like overdoing it and that it might seem like the compiler should be able to figure it out. The fact is though, that the compiler often doesn't.

What I mean is to change code like this

```
UINT16* pBlackVal = (UINT16*)(pBlack->data + i*pBlack->step[0]);
```

into this

```
// Before first loop:
UINT16* blackData = (UINT16*) pBlack->data;
yourType blackStep = (yourType) pBlack->step[0];

...

UINT16* pBlackVal = (UINT16*)(blackData + i*blackStep);
```

to avoid generating any code that would chase pointers to data that could be evicted from the cache. The same goes for `pMatSrc->size[0]` and `pWhite->step[0]` etc. Especially do it for `(*pData)` in `nDif = (*pData) - (*pBlackVal);`.

This is a general recommendation in any code that might be performance sensitive, don't blindly assume that the compiler will solve your problems, especially when it comes to memory reads/writes.

Incrementing variables using prefix notation instead of postfix COULD help, but I suspect compilers are smart enough here. But why chance it? The reason is that if you use prefix, the previous value of the variable does not have to be remembered, since the prefix increment notation increments the value BEFORE it can be used instead of after. I might be a bit too picky here though. :)

You can use tools to inspect cache misses to determine if these transformations help. See for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385772.aspx.

## Memory patterns

Next, I recommend that you look through your memory read patterns to see if you could store your data in memory in a way that would make it more cache friendly.

The first thing that comes to mind here, since you're doing effectively 2D arrays with your matrices, is that you must iterate over your matrix to match the data layout, otherwise you'll destroy performance.

What I mean is that if you store the matrix

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

like this in memory

```
abcdefghi
```

then you should iterate like this

```
for r in [0, rowLength-1]
    for c in [0, columnLength-1]
        // do thing with data[rowLength * r + c] here
```

i.e. you iterate over every column in a row before skipping to the next row. If you do it the otherway around, you program will run super slow.

If you are already doing this or not is unclear. It depends on the values of `pMatDst->step[1]` and `pMatDst->step[2]`. Make sure the inner loop jumps the shortest distance possible through the array, basically, so you want `pMatDst->step[1]` to be much smaller than `pMatDst->step[2]`.

What you want to do is to read memory linearly. The memory systems in computers are great at prefetching data and caching it to make that fast. The best is of course to not read memory at all if you can help it. Also try to do all you need do with a piece of memory after reading it before moving on to the next thing instead of reading it over and over again.

## Links

To learn more about how memory use and layouts affect performance, I recommend reading the "Pitfalls of Object Oriented Programming" presentation (hope this works http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/_pdf/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf).

Another great resource is Mike Acton's talk on data oriented design at CppCon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc, albeit a bit less specific.

Comment: I followed your advices, but the gain in performances was marginal, improving the speed by a factor of 3.5% (according to my benchmark tests).

Comment: Cool, you got some gains. :) What are your typical values of `pMatSrc->size[0/1]` and `pMatSrc->step[0/1]`? Could you post your new code as an update?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a inverse (I mean multiplicative inverse) table for that. If you allow some little imprecision, this table will fit in 128k. It won't fit L1 cache. So, maybe you'll need to prefetch it to maximize performance. With SIMD, this solution should be faster than your current one.

If your white image happens to be constant (I mean that you call `CalibrationFunction` multiple times with the same white image), then you can invert it before, so you won't need the inverse table, and the solution will be even faster.